# In my Laytout getting some space between image and text

Tags: android, xml

[image]sorry for my bad English ,I am new to android ,in my layout i am getting space between image and text view here below my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.clelerbity.MainActivity" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="214dp"
      android:layout_height="150dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:src="@drawable/arjun" />

      <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="145dp"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
      android:background="#FF00FF"
      android:text="TextView"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

please help me any one how to achive this

[image]

Comment: You don't need an extra LinearLayout. Just use a **compound drawable** in your TextView.

Comment: You xml is not completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed orientation.

```
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ImageView
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="214dp"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:src="@drawable/arjun" />

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="145dp"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
  android:background="#FF00FF"
  android:text="TextView"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: again I am getting gap between image and text

Comment: Add android:scaleType="centerCrop" in Imageview . I think it's not gap . Try Imageview setbackground to Blue and Textview setbackground to Yellow. Look is there gap between blue and yellow.

Comment: I added screen short @tiny sunlight

Comment: Did you update your xml? add android:scaleType="centerCrop" or  android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: yes but again ,getting space between image and text

Comment: can u please post whole xml code for that design @tiny sunlight

Answer (score 0):

please use **android:layout_gravity="left"**

Comment: i did that but i am getting space between image and text

Comment: yes but still i am getting same gap between image and text

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this many views try compound view, Bellow i was give a solution it may be help full to you.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF00FF"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arjun"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use layout which is not required. just check once the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.clelerbity.MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arjun" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:background="#FF00FF"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is the solution...

First take relative layout instead of linear layout ...Below is the code ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.example.clelerbity.MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="214dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arjun" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView1"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    < /RelativeLayout>
```

It may helpful to you...